# encoding PHP array to Javascript (JSON)

Tags: php, arrays, json

how do I get `[{}]` in JSON? If I encode `array()` in PHP, the JSON result is `[]`. What is `[{}]` in JS anyway?

Thanks

Comment: `[{}]` is an array containing a single empty object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use: `array(new stdClass)` which when `json_encode`d, should end up to be `[{}]`

To answer your second question of "what is `[{}]` anyway?", well it is simple:

it's an array, whose only element is an object with no members in it.

Answer (score 1):

`[{}]` is an array containing an object. JSON is an object and you can have a JSONArray within it and more objects within that. Don't overthink the data structure :)